# Access controls from WPF project in nomal winforms project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

I have an application thats completed and working perfectly .Its a normal winforms projects.I have another class library application thats developed in WPF and i have referred this wpf application in normal winform application and calling this WPF windows in that winform application.
Now i need to access the **controls** of a window from wpf application in this winform application .Is it possible..??

I tried and some told to  add this property in xaml page of wpf application.
     x:FieldModifier="public"
Icouldn't access the control in winforms even after adding this property.
**Is it possoble to access controls of a window from wpf application in winform application..?If so any tutorial for it..?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a ElementHost Control

[Host a Windows Presentation Foundation Control in Windows Forms by Using ElementHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754008(v=vs.90).aspx)